# Python Static Thread Variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a number of threads in my software that all do the same thing, but each thread operates from a different "perspective." I have a "StateModel" object that is used throughout the thread and the objects within the thread, but StateModel needs to be calculated differently for each thread.

I don't like the idea of passing the StateModel object around to all of the functions that need it. Normally, I would create a module variable and all of the objects throughout the program could reference the same data from the module variable. But, is there a way to have this concept of a static module variable that is different and independent for each thread? A kind of static Thread variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off using Multiprocessing instead of multithreading for this use case. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is implemented in [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local).

I tend to dislike mostly-quoting-the-docs answers, but... well, time and place for everything.

> A class that represents thread-local data. Thread-local data are data
>   whose values are thread specific. To manage thread-local data, just
>   create an instance of local (or a subclass) and store attributes on
>   it:
>
> ```
> mydata = threading.local() 
> mydata.x = 1
> ```
>
> The instance’s values will be
>   different for separate threads.
>
> For more details and extensive examples, see the documentation string
>   of the [`_threading_local`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/_threading_local.py) module.

Notably you can just have your class extend `threading.local`, and suddenly your class has thread-local behavior.

Comment: Great answer! I don't know why I wasn't able to find this when I was googling. I guess I was searching the wrong key words. Thanks Roippi!